# Why is my jquery executing on second click only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a jQuery function which updates a div upon clicking another div. However, it is only firing on the second click each time and I'm rather confused.

How can I fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".block-swatch").click(function(){
    $("#refresh-feefo").load(window.location.href + " #refresh-feefo" );
  }); 
});
```

Comment: `+ " #refresh-feefo"` should probably be `+ "#refresh-feefo"`

Comment: thank you for getting back to me, if i remove this gap it actually reloads the whole window inside the div and not just the div.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) as it allow to bind event from a parent and if your DOM element `#refresh-feefo` isn't ready, it will still work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("body").on('click', '.block-swatch', () => {
    $("#refresh-feefo").load(window.location.href + " #refresh-feefo" );
  }); 
});
```

I used `body` , but be careful:

> Hierarchical selectors can often be avoided simply by attaching the handler to a more appropriate point in the document. For example, instead of $( "body" ).on( "click", "#commentForm .addNew", addComment ) use $( "#commentForm" ).on( "click", ".addNew", addComment ).

Read **Event performance** section here for more: https://api.jquery.com/on/